# Making only a part of the legend title bold in R

Tags: r, legend

I have a legend title spread over two lines, I would like to make only the first line bold. I have the following code:

```
pre_legend_title = expression(paste(bold("PRE-ELECTION HATE CRIME RATES"),
                                    "\nAverage annual hate crimes per 100,000 residents, 2010-15"))
```

However, when I try adding it to my ggplot using:

```
labs(fill = pre_legend_title)
```

The title doesn't break into two lines despite using \n. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious why you want this to be an extended legend title, why not use the `title` and `subtitle` arguments to `labs`?

Comment: @KevinArseneau I think those arguments only refer to the main title and subtitle of the plot, which I've already used. I'm interested in modifying the legend title.

Comment: That is correct, they refer to the plot and not the legend. However, your example text is not what someone would expect as a legend title. The answer provided seems to solve your problem, I was only looking to understand the context, which is unusual.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, `expression` doesn't recognize linebreak characters. However, you can use the `atop` function:

```
library(ggplot2)

pre_legend_title = expression(atop(bold("PRE-ELECTION HATE CRIME RATES"),
                                   "Average annual hate crimes per 100,000 residents, 2010-15"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  labs(fill = pre_legend_title)
```

[image]